# An integration question which involves the unit one

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

When integrating a function, and the integration function is multiplied by 1, do I multiply by one or integrate the one?

I say this because, if the function is 1, then this integrates?

for example:

1. $$ \int^{2}_{-2} cos\frac{n\pi t}{2}1dt $$

as opposed to
2. $$ \int^{2}_{-2} 1dt $$

Why is it, that 1) I can only multiply it by 1 as opposed to integrating the cos function by *t* and 1 over *t*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you can just multiply the one; there is never any harm in  that. However, you can make use of the one in integration by parts. Anything multiplied by one is itself, so you can always makes use of it like so:

[image]

With integration by parts, we can integrate the x and differentiate the ln(x), which is helpful because we can't integrate what we are already trying to find the integral of.
I know this wasn't an exact answer, but I hope this puts some insight into the one.

Answer (score 0):

A factor $1$ can always be implied. $f(x)=1\cdot f(x)=1\cdot1\cdot f(x)=\cdots$. So if you tried to integrate these factors, you would get a nonsense.

Comment: Are there any restrictions that prevent the implication of multiple ones in an integration?

Comment: @Meilton: did you understand my argument ?

Comment: Plenty. You mention that "A factor 1 can always be implied", given this statement, "Are there any restrictions that prevent the implication of multiple ones in an integration?". Possibly, I was looking for a more technical term than "nonsense"

Comment: @Meilton: in fact I don't understand "Are there any restrictions that prevent the implication of multiple ones in an integration?"